# Try Catch failing to obtain variables

Tags: powershell, try-catch

I have variables which I've imported via a CSV. However, when I attempt to run the below try/catch from within a foreach loop (which is parsing through the CSV), the ID variable is dropped. If I run one of the statements within the foreach (without the try/catch) this works as expected.

```
#Send Emails
try {

    Send-ToEmail -email "$($_.EmailAddress)";

    #Set Success Status
    $SqlCmd = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand
    $SqlCmd.Connection = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection
    $SqlCmd.Connection.ConnectionString = $ConnectionString
    $SqlCmd.Connection.Open()
    $SqlCmd.CommandText = "UPDATE STATUSES SET STATUS = 2 WHERE ID = $($_.ID)"
    $SqlCmd.ExecuteNonQuery()

}

catch {
    "Failure Sending Email"

    #Set failure Status
    Echo "Updating Email Queue"
    $SqlCmd = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand
    $SqlCmd.Connection = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection
    $SqlCmd.Connection.ConnectionString = $ConnectionString
    $SqlCmd.Connection.Open()
    $SqlCmd.CommandText = "UPDATE STATUSES SET STATUS = 3 WHERE ID = $($_.ID)"
    $SqlCmd.ExecuteNonQuery()

}
```

Comment: Inside the `catch`, the `$_` automatic variable holds the error itself, **not the original object**. Create a variable before the `try..catch` like `$user = $_` and use that variable inside the try and catch blocks instead of `$_`

Comment: Hi @Theo, that makes sense. Would it be possible to provide an example? I tried Boxdog's suggestion which was similar, but this didn't work.

Comment: It would be helpful if you could show the outer loop that is stepping through the CSV file.  Also, how are you reading the CSV file?  Are you using Import-CSV?  Why is SQlCmd needed?

Comment: If the `ID` is missing in both the try aswell as the catch block, then there is something wrong with the CSV file you are using. Are you sure the header of that column is called `ID` (no spaces around it or something?) Put in a couple of `Write-Host` cmdlets so you can check inside each iteration you do have the values you are expecting.

Answer (score 0):

Inside a `catch` block, the `$_` variable is used to hold the exception record.  Try assigning your pipeline object to a separate variable and reference that in the `catch`.  For example:

```
$csvContent |
  Foreach-Object {
    $currentObject = $_

    try {
      # Do stuff
    }
    catch {
      # More stuff
      $SqlCmd.CommandText = "UPDATE STATUSES SET STATUS = 3 WHERE ID = $($currentObject.ID)"
      # Even more stuff
    }
  }
```

Comment: Alternatively, use a conventional foreach-loop. `foreach ($csvElement in $csvContent){}`

Comment: Unfortunately the ID variable still appears to be blank

Answer (score 0):

It will not work because $_ / $PsItem variables get the value from pipelines. So remove the $_. Part from the variables.